# How to put db name into query using %s

Tags: python, mysql

I have a following sql query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM %s.tableA
```

The tableA is in `db-jablonec` so I need to call `db-jablonec.tableA`.

I use this method in Python:

```py
def my_method(self, expedice):

   self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

   query = """
   SELECT *
   FROM %s.tableA    
   """

   self.cursor.execute(query, [expedice])
   df = pd.DataFrame(self.cursor.fetchall())
```

I call it like this:

```py
expedice = ["db-jablonec"]
for exp in expedice:
    df = db.my_method(exp)
```

But I got an error `MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table ''db-jablonec'.tableA' doesn't exist")` 
Obviously, I want to call `'db-jablonec.tableA'` not `''db-jablonec'.tableA'`. How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is passing %s as its own string including the quotes `''`

you therefore need to pass it as one variable. Concatenate .table to the variable itself then pass it in.

Your query will therefore then be

```
query = """
   SELECT *
   FROM %s    
   """
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helpful for you

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%%'
```

[Refer This.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.7/en/information-schema.html)